# Automatically move MS Word bookmark after an insertion at this point

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

H ey folks,

I've assembled the following code, which copies the first table in my Word document and inserts it at a bookmark position and also adds a formated heading above it via a second bookmark.

To fully automate my Excel application however, I need an advanced functionality of my code. After an insertion was done, the bookmarks have to be relocated to a position directly above the newly inserted table / heading.

Is it possible to relocate these bookmarks programmatically? 
Any help is much appreciated.

Best regards,
daZza

Code:

```
Sub Main()

Dim doc As Word.document
Set doc = GetObject("xxxx.docx")

doc.Tables(1).Range.Copy
doc.bookmarks("AH_Tab").Range.Paste

doc.bookmarks("AH_Header").Range.Text = "Test"
doc.bookmarks("AH_Header").Range.Style = wdStyleHeading1

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code before `End Sub`

```
Dim tmpRng As Range
Set tmpRng = doc.Bookmarks("AH_Header").Range
doc.Bookmarks.Add "AH_Header", ActiveDocument.Range(tmpRng.Start - 1, tmpRng.Start - 1)
```

Additional information:

- do the same for second bookmark
- by changing -1 values you can expand
  & move the range where exactly the new bookmark should be placed